# Java reference variables

Tags: java, pointers, pass-by-reference

I know Java does not permit pointers a la C++. However, I have heard something about references (presumably similar to C++ also). My question relates to the following problem:

I have a class "A", say, a bunch of which I instantiate (using new) in memory, and I wish to "link" these classes to one another depending on how I choose. In C++ I would just have a vector (defined in class A) of class A pointers to which I add pointers to the instances of class A I want to link to. This is basically like building an omnidirectional graph in memory (or unidirectional depending on how I construct my links)

My question is can I do this in Java in an elegant way, and how? I'm guessing it's something to do with references. Pointers seem such a simple solution to this problem, but I'm new to Java and learning how to do such things without pointers. I'm not really sure how to define a reference. In C++ I would have used the A * mypointer = new A();

Thanks,

Comment: In C, there are no vectors and no `new`. You're thinking about C++. In Java, everything (except the built-in types) have reference semantics.

Comment: In java you will do everything the same, but you won't put a little `*` in front of the classes you're linking.

Comment: In Java you pass copies of references to methods, not references. If it would be the references themselve, you could change them in the method, which is, what a reference is in C++, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the goal typically isn't to change the reference, but to change the object it references (which works fine in java). Using my answer as an example, if a `FunkyObject` iterates over its `referenceList` and calls a method named `changeName` on each item, the original `FunkyObject`'s will be modified as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry @larsmans, that was a typo. Well spotted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class FunkyObject
{
    /** a list of other FunkyObject that this object is linked to */

    List<FunkyObject> referenceList = new ArrayList<FunkyObject>();

    /** creates a link between this object and someObject */

    public addRefrerence(FunkyObject someObject )
    {
        referenceList.add(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A {

    private A[] refs;

    public A(A... refs) {
        this.refs = refs;
    }
}
```

Comment: `In C I would just have a vector (defined in class A) of class A pointers to which I add pointers to the instances of class A I want to link to.` sounds a bit like adding without knowing before how big the collection is, so Array seems not a suitable choice here, for me.

Comment: That's why I suggest a list in my answer, but whether you use an array or a list shouldn't matter.

Comment: yes, the number of links is undefined, that's why in C++ I would have used some kind of unbounded container such as a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of references as pointers since they refer to the instance just as a pointer points to a memory location. The big difference is that Java doesn't allow *arithmetic* on references as C does on pointers. You also cannot create a reference to a field--only to an object and only by instantiating it with `new`.

As for storing references to several instances of `A`, you have many options. You can use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) such as [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or any of the other [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) classes. It really depends on how you need to access them. Peruse through the `java.util` package for all of the collections.

Comment: I think it does injustice to say "[object] references are pointers without arithmetic"...

Comment: @pst - Can you be more specific. Someone who understands C pointers will understand Java references pretty well since they are similar.

Comment: @pst [Wittgenstein's ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) applies. If the purpose of this question would be to explain the difference between Java and C, the "injustice" would be relevant. For the purposes of explaining how to do what you want to do in Java, it can be useful to use a simpler, "close enough" metaphor. (That said, in this case "lack of pointer arithmetic" isn't IMO the crucial difference, as much as the one added in the edit.)

Comment: @Inerdial I disagree and think that the entire semantics can be described without the use of "references" entirely: While it *is* important to keep in mind that the term "reference" *is* used in the JLS, the concept can be described entirely without the term "references", as evidenced with the ECMAScript specification. I just fail to see trying to establish a further connection... let language X go. (And it's actually more confusing coming from C++, where references *are* already a language construct, but not entirely in the Java sense...)

Comment: @pst: I think we can quote the JLS: "reference values (often just *references*) are pointers to ... objects" (JLS 4.3.1)

Comment: @newacct Indeed. And hence why I made explicitly made sure to *acknowledge* as such early on in my previous comment. However, I believe the rest still stands and the semantics can be described cleanly without such terms -- *after* which it's easy to talk about the terminology used in said language.

Comment: That is, even though Java, Python and JavaScript all have the same concept of "reference types", they all use different terminology. In Java one would "Call by Value of The Reference". In Python one uses "Pass by Reference" (nevermind the overloaded nature of this phrase) in JavaScript there is no mention of the term "reference" even though the "Call by Object Sharing" semantics are well-defined. In Python a variable "is a name binding to an object" while in Java a [reference-typed] variable "contains a [value of the] reference to an object", etc.

Comment: So that was sort of a tangent but I think it's important to start out "clean" with the conceptual distinction and *then* allow the "oh, so that's like [or not like] X in language Y"...

Answer (score 0):

What you described in the second paragraph is pretty much exactly how Java's model works. (It's also the only way it works.) When Java tutorials say that "Java is pass-by-value", the values they mean are primitive types, and *object handles*. That is, when you pass an object-typed value around, the object doesn't get copied. (Which I believe is the same behaviour as passing a pointer to a struct around in C.)

What you, for instance, can not do is create a pointer pointing to a local variable or object field. You can only pass around their values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help - it has been very useful. It seems references provide the elegant solution I was looking for, which pointers offer in C/C++. The only main difference I can see so far (without actually implementing) is that we cannot perform arithmetic on references.